# Git Switch/Checkout to this

Tags: git

I got myself in a mess and was wondering if you could help?
There is probably a lot to it, so I was hoping to get the jist of what I need to do.

- Rev 10 Does not compile correctly.
- Rev 07 - Compiles correctly. I want to see what the difference between Rev 07 and Rev 08 to figure out what went wrong, then Integrate those changes into Rev 10.
- I need to verify commits 08 and 09 to see if they can compile or not.

This is what I think I need to do:

1. I committed and pushed to save my changes. (Maybe I could have stashed the changes, but I don't know how to do that just yet.)
2. Show Log
3. Switch/Check out to this (Rev 09)

   - I don't want to create a branch. I just want to see if it compiles.
     After I am done, I think I can just switch back to Rev 10 where I left off. If my thinking is correct?
   - I wan't to select 'Overwrite working tree changes (force)', because
     I have already committed and pushed my working files.

Maybe I am wrong, but I don't think I have to create a branch every time I switch to a certain checkout. All I want to do is verify the version compiles, then go back to where I left off.

P.S. I am trying to accomplish this with Windows GIT (if you couldn't tell). I can get the jist of the Unix commands.

P.S.S If it isn't too much to ask, I was also thinking of making version 07 version 11. Get rid of the versions that don't compile, instead of making another "Working Branch". What would be the correct way to do something like that. Extra thanks.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with checking out an earlier revision on its own is that it leaves your repo in “headless” mode. Unlike Subversion, Git doesn’t remember which revision you are on if it isn’t the tip of a branch.

To properly keep track of things, you need to create a temporary branch at that earlier revision, e.g.:

```
git checkout -b temp_branch older_commit
```

This is easy to do, and you can always delete the branch later — remember that “`git-branch -d`” will only delete “fully-merged” branches, which such a temporary branch will be, so such a deletion will be quite safe.